# How can I remove the disabled attribute of a textbox by clicking the nearby radio button?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a form which contain the following section:

```
<ul class="fb-a-col">
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Business" class="" /><label>Business</label> </li>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Salaried Person" class="" /><label>Salaried Person</label>   </li>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Agriculture" class="" /><label>Agriculture</label>   </li>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Student" class="" /><label>Student </label>  </li>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Home Maker" class="" /><label>Home Maker</label> </li>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Others" class="" onclick="release(this)" /><label>Others</label> </li>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation_others" id="cust_occupation_others" type="text" class="readonly" disabled="disabled" /></li>
</ul>
```

**when I click the "Others" option, it should remove the "disabled" property of the next text box with class="readonly".**

I want to do this without jQuery, so how can I do this with pure javascript, can someone help?

> note:
>   I have 5 such sets of ul's in the form.

Comment: _"...the next text box with class="readonly""_ - That's not actually what `.closest()` does, `.closest()` searches up through an element's ancestors, not through cousins or siblings.

Comment: I know that, but I can get the object of the closest textbox with that class name right?

Comment: Also your markup is invalid, you shouldn't have the `<input>` as a direct child of the `<ul>` - not good when you try to do DOM traversal (or in general). Please fix that first so that any solutions that people suggest can start from valid html.

Comment: Guys comeon! If i am wrong, please correct it, don't start pin pointing! I agree I misunderstood jQuery closest(), so you could have edited my post with so much rep.\

Comment: ok keep that last `input` in `li` tag because "unordered list" contains "list-items"..

Comment: @shathish—we don't know what you want, hence the questions in comments. You can edit your question in response.

Comment: @RobG: sorry I don't get you! do you want me to edit the question or should i give more detail on what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parentNode` and then `nextSibling` (and then `firstChild`, now that the input is [corectly] in an `li`):

```
function release(element) {
    // Get the radio button's parent's next sibling
    var elm = element.parentNode.nextSibling;

    // Skip any intervening text nodes
    while (elm && elm.nodeType !== 1) {
        elm = elm.nextSibling;
    }

    // If we found the `li`, enable the `input` inside it
    if (elm) {
        elm.firstChild.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

You can read all about the DOM here: http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR

Now, the above assumes that the radio button will always be a direct child of the `li`, which jQuery's `closest` doesn't assume. But that's the case in your HTML. If it weren't, you'd just use a loop:

```
var input = element;
while (input && input.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "LI") {
    input = input.parentNode;
    if (input && input.tagName.toUpperCase() === "HTML") {
        input = null;
    }
}
// Input is either null or the closest LI
```

Comment: [just asking] Any reason not to use "parentElement" and "nextElementSibling"? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cBXLM/).

Comment: @Mr_Green: There's basically never any reason to use `parentElement` that I've ever seen, since of course the parent node of an element is always either the element or the document. :-) There's no harm in it, though, AFAIK. Re `nextElementSibling`, I have to admit that I stopped doing DOM-direct stuff (I use jQuery now) long enough ago that support wasn't robust enough and I just never got used to using it. I think it's near-universally supported now, though, isn't it? So that would be a good way to go.

Comment: yeah just got confused as both 50k+ users are not using it :D

Comment: @Mr_Green: Turns out we're right to avoid it: [MDN claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.nextElementSibling) that it's not even in IE8! As something like 20% of the world's web users use IE8, and that's the latest version of IE for XP...

Answer (score 1):

The last `input` was not inside a `li`, I have moved it inside a `li` in the fiddle

```
function findEl(curr, path){
    while(curr && curr.nodeType != 1){
        curr = curr[path]
    }
    return curr;
}

function release(el){
    if(el.checked){
        var next = findEl(el.parentNode.nextSibling, 'nextSibling');
        var inp = findEl(next.firstChild, 'nextSibling');
        inp.disabled = false
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zdu9R/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [*closest*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function goes through ancestors, it appears you want to go through siblings that are lower in the DOM.

> when I click the "Others" option, it should remove the "disabled"
>   property of the next text box with class="readonly".

"Others" is a radio button. When it's checked, you want to find the next input element in the DOM with a class of "readonly".

Your markup is invalid, an input element can't be a sibling of an LI element or child of a UL, so likely browser error correction will move the input to after the UL and the resulting DOM fragment is like:

```
<ul class="fb-a-col">
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" ...>
     <li><input name="cust_occupation" type="radio" value="Others"
         onclick="release(this)"><label>Others</label>
</ul>
<input name="cust_occupation_others" id="cust_occupation_others" type="text"
 class="readonly" disabled="disabled">
```

So what you are trying to get is the next element sibling of the UL, which can be done in a specific case with:

```
function release(el) {
   var li = el.parentNode;
   var ul = li.parentNode;
   var re = /(^|\s)readonly(\s|$)/;

   do {
     ul = ul.nextSibling;
     if (ul && ul.nodeType == 1 && re.test(ul.className)) {
       return ul;
     }
  } while (ul)
}
```

Another strategy is to get all the input elements in the document, find the one that was clicked on, then return the next one with class *readonly*:

```
function release(el) {
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var re = /(^|\s)readonly(\s|$)/;
   var start = false;
   var input;

   for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
     input = inputs[i];

     if (input == el) {
       start = true;
     }
     if (start) {
       if (re.test(input.className)) {
         return input;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

You could use a similar strategy using querySelectorAll, but *getElementsByTagName* is more widely supported and sufficient.